# Memory leaks in Angular App caused by JQuery

Tags: jquery, angular, memory

We are working on development on a Angular app and sometimes one model (in our case JobModel) remains hanged in memory caused by JQuery.

JobModel hanged by job - > sort -> options -> current -> ddmanager -> ui - > Jquery.

The chain of reference is visible in the attached image from a heap memory screenshot: [image]

How can I solve this issue and how can I remove hanged objects?